# What is the basis of the hyperreal numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, nonstandard-analysis

Let us consider the [Hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) as a vector space over the real numbers. This vector space is quite interesting.

Here are some interesting subspaces:

- The finite numbers
- The infinitesimal numbers

My question is, what is a basis of the Hyperreal numbers?

Comment: The hyperreals have cardinality stricter greater than that of the continuum.  You're not going to be able to write down a basis.

Comment: The span of the hyperintegers does contain infinitesimals. For example, [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) says there are infinitely large hyperintegers $P$ and $Q$ such that $$\left| \frac{P}{Q} - \pi\right| < \frac{1}{Q^2}$$ This implies that $P - \pi \cdot Q$ is infinitesimal.

Comment: What's a basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q?$  That sounds easier, but you won't be able to exhibit one.

Comment: @D_S The standard ultrapower construction of the hyperreals produces a model of size continuum.

Comment: @PyRulez The question is ill-posed unless you specify the model or method of construction of the hyperreals you have in mind.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Uhm, probably just the standard ultrapower construction will due (I thought all constructions were isomorphic, right?).

Comment: No, there is no categoricity here.

Comment: (Also, there is nothing like *the* basis. Bases are not unique.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo isn't that unique up to isomorphism too, or isn't that true either?

Comment: Isomorphism of what? Any two bases will have the same size. And yes, trivially any bijection between bases extends to an automorphism of the space. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo yeah

Comment: @PyRulez there are always Hammel-type bases but in this case I am not sure this would provide a useful tool.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if one is allowed to consider infinite sums in $*\Bbb{R}$ (that is, a sum indexed in $*\Bbb{N}$), I believe I found one generating set that is almost a base.

First, considering binary representations, for each positive real number $x$, there is a sequence $(..., a_1, a_0, a_{-1}, ...)$, $a_n \in \{0, 1\}$ of bits such that $$x = ... a_2 4 + a_1 2 + a_0 + a_1 2^{-1} + a_2 2^{-2}...$$ There exists an $n_0$ such that $a_{n_0}=1$ and $a_n=0$ for $n > n_0$.

Applying the transfer principle, we conclude that the set $$B = \{2^n : n \in *\Bbb{Z}\}$$ is a generating set of vectors. But we can filter it a little more.

Consider two nonzero hyperreals $u$ and $v$ and say that they are equivalent if $u/v$, $v/u$ are both finite. This equivalence tells, roughly, that $u$ and $v$ have comparable magnitude, and in particular they are either both infinite, both real, or both infinitesimal.

Now, let $\beta$ be a set with one unique element of each equivalence class in $B$.

For any hiperreal $x$, assume w.l.g. that it is positive and write it as above. There is a $2^{m_0}$ in $\beta$ which is equivalent to $2^{n_0}$. Since $x - 2^{n_0} \leq 2^{n_0}$, $2^{m_0}$ is also equivalent to $x$. Therefore, $x 2^{-m_0} = b_0 + \delta$ where $b_0$ is real and $\delta$ is an infinitesimal. Then, $x = b_0 2^{m_0} + x_1$, where $x_1$ is infinitesimal with respect to $x$.

Now we apply transfinite induction or Zorn's lemma (by ordering representations of $x$) and write

$$x = b_0 2^{m_0} + b_1 2^{m_1} + b_2 2^{m_2} + \dots$$

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work: the transfinite construction you propose breaks down at limit steps, because such infinite sums of hyperreal numbers are not well-defined (they will almost never converge).

Comment: I believe this is a basis because the choice of $b_0$ is unique and there is a unique element in $\beta$ that is equivalent to $x$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm not sure whether that's relevant - this construction looks analogous to the notion of a Schauder basis, which doesn't require that every infinite linear combination converge.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: The problem is that in order to define $m_\omega$ and $b_\omega$ you need to know what $\sum_{n<\omega} b_n2^{m_n}$ is but that sum may not converge.

Comment: @EricWofsey ah yes, I understand now.